# is coq match statement exhaustive?

Tags: coq

If i have a snippet similar to this one:

```
Inductive Q : Set := 
| NULL : Q
| CELL : nat -> Q -> Q -> Q
.

Definition someFunc (q: Q) := 
match q with
| NULL => True
| CELL 0 -> q1 -> q2 => True
| CELL z -> q1 -> q2 => (someFunc q1) || (someFunc q2)

end.
```

Will the case where q is `0 -> Q -> Q -> Q` exhaust the match and finish the function execution, or will it drop down the next branch and destructure 0 as z?

Comment: Your code has syntax errors. A pattern that matches the constructor `CELL` applied to three values `z`, `q1`, `q2` is written `CELL 0 q1 q2`. The arrows `->` are for function types. Could you fix it before we can answer your question?

Comment: In fact there are more issues with your code. First, your definition of `someFunc` should be a `Fixpoint` since you are trying to call it recursively.
Second, there seems to be a confusion between booleans (`true` and `false`) and propositions (`True`, `False`, `True \/ False` and so on): `True` is a proposition but `||` is for boolean disjunction (the disjunction for propositions is written `\/`). Also, the import for that notation is missing; please provide a viable minimal example.

Answer (score 0):

The title of you question is not representative of the mistakes you made in your original question.  You think you have a problem with exhaustive pattern-matching (you don't), while you have a mere problem of syntax and basic typing.

- You managed to define an type of trees (called `Q`) with two constructors.  That part is good.
- You attempted to define a function, which by the look of it, is a recursive function.  When defining a recursive function, you should use the keyword `Fixpoint`.
- When writing a pattern in a pattern match construct, you have to respect the syntax for function application.  So what you wrote `Cell 0 -> q1 -> q2` should probably be written `Cell 0 q1 q2`.
- The values returned in different branches of the pattern-match construct are in different type: `True` has type `Prop`, while an expression of the form `(someFunc q1) || (someFunc q2)` has type `bool`.  These are two different types.  There are two different notions of `or` connectives for these two types.  One is written `||`  the other one (which you should have used) is written `\/`.

So here is an example of code that is similar to yours, but does not suffer with syntax or typing problems.

```
Inductive Q : Set := 
| NULL : Q
| CELL : nat -> Q -> Q -> Q
.

Fixpoint someFunc (q: Q) := 
match q with
| NULL => True
| CELL 0 q1 q2 => True
| CELL z q1 q2 => (someFunc q1) \/ (someFunc q2)
end.
```

Maybe reading a few more examples of existing Coq code would help you get a better feeling of the syntax.  The [supplementary material of the Coq'Art book](https://github.com/coq-community/coq-art/) provides a few of these examples (in particular, you can look at the material for chapter 1 and chapter 6).